# Use delay load to load correct library - return value type error

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-errors, return-value, delay-load

I used msdn documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0fkfy9y(v=vs.100).aspx

It specifies there that:

```
case dliNotePreLoadLibrary :
//If you want to return control to the helper, return 0.
//Otherwise, return your own HMODULE to be used by the 
//instead of having it call LoadLibrary itself
```

So I tried the following:

```
FARPROC WINAPI delayHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{
    switch (dliNotify) {
        case dliStartProcessing :
        case dliNotePreGetProcAddress :
        case dliFailLoadLib :
        case dliFailGetProc :
        case dliNoteEndProcessing : 
          return 0;
          break;
        case dliNotePreLoadLibrary :
            {
                char* dllPath = getDllPath();
                HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
                return lib;
            }
            break;      
        default :
            return NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I get error for returning the HMODULE:

> 'return' : cannot convert from 'HMODULE' to 'FARPROC'.

What is the problem? Am I doing something worng? they do say return your own HMODULE, and that is what I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadLibrary()` returns an `HMODULE`. Your `delayHook()` function returns a `FARPROC`. So there is a mismatch in return value.
Assuming that you really want to return `HMODULE` returned by `LoadLibrary()`, you may want to use a cast like `reinterpret_cast`:

```
case dliNotePreLoadLibrary :
{
    char* dllPath = getDllPath();
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
    return reinterpret_cast<FARPROC>(lib);
}
```

Side note: in today's world, you should use Unicode instead of ANSI/MBCS, so your `dllPath` should better be a Unicode string (e.g. `const wchar_t*`, or `CString`, or `std::wstring`).

Answer (score 0):

So you should simply cast it to `FARPROC`:

```
return (FARPROC)lib;
```